# Is Assessment Bias a type of Observer Bias?

Tags: bias, clinical-trials

Based on the definitions of assessment bias and observer bias I have found bellow, seems like assessment bias is a type of observer bias?

Assessment bias:

> If the observer knows the treatment being given to the patient and if
> the measurement of an outcome variable contains an element of
> subjectivity, then it is possible that the value of an observation
> might be influenced by the knowledge of the treatment. For example, in
> a trial of treatments designed to reduce blood pressure, the
> observer’s views on the effectiveness of a treatment may affect his
> judgment of when the noise of a pulse can be Heard.

source: Introduction to Randomized Controlled Clinical Trials, John N.S Matthews

Observer bias:

> Observer bias is a type of detection bias that can affect assessment
> in observational and interventional studies. Parta’s Dictionary of
> Epidemiology gives the following definition: “Systematic difference
> between a true value and the value actually observed due to observer
> variation” and continues to describe observer variation.
>
> Many healthcare observations are open to systematic variation. For
> example, in the assessment of medical images, one observer might
> record an abnormality but another might not. Different observers might
> tend to round up or round down a measurement scale. Colour change
> tests can be interpreted differently by different observers. Where
> subjective judgement is part of the observation, there is great
> potential for variability between observers, and some of these
> differences might be systematic and lead to bias. Observation of
> objective data, such as death, is at much lower risk of observer bias.
>
> Biases in recording objective data may result from inadequate training
> in the use of measurement devices or data sources or unchecked bad
> habits. By recording subjective data, predispositions of the observer
> are likely to underpin observer biases. Observers might be somewhat
> conscious of their own biases about a study or may be unaware of
> factors influencing their decisions when recording study information.
>
> Randomized controlled trials are designed to provide the fairest test
> of an intervention. However, if any part of the data collection
> process involves observation, observer bias can affect the measurement
> in the study.
>
> Example Observer bias has been repeatedly been documented in studies
> of blood pressure. Clinicians measuring participants blood pressure
> using mercury sphygmomanometers have been found to round up, or down,
> readings to the nearest whole number. Observer bias may also occur if
> the researcher has a preconceived idea of what the blood pressure
> ought to be, leading to arbitrary adjustments of the readings.

source:https://catalogofbias.org/biases/observer-bias/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'm not sure it matters a whole lot. I guess it's kind of interesting to try to make a list of biases that is as exhaustive as possible and mutually exclusive. Probably this should be a hierarchical (or nested) list. But I don't think disagreements about how this list should be organized will affect statistical practice.

Second, different definitions will yield different answers.

Third, to actually answer your question based on the definitions you give, as I was reading the definition of "observer bias" I was inclined to say "no" but the last line of the definition changed my mind. In assessment bias the observer definitely has an idea of what the answer should be and this idea biases their reporting.